# Why doesn't this regex work for recurring pairs?

Tags: javascript, regex

The regex is trying to match only terms not between two markers. The markers are always equally paired.

Running this:

```
test(?=(?:[^<]*<[^>]*>)*[^<]*$)
wehtestouiewgt<test>aiosuuotestasdhjp<ottesther>asofatestsofg<trash>sjd
```

Should match:

`weh*test*ouiewgt<test>aiosuuo*test*asdhjp<ottesther>asofa*test*sofg<trash>sjd`

But for some reason it matches:

`weh*test*ouiewgt<*test*>aiosuuo*test*asdhjp<ot*test*her>asofa*test*sofg<trash>sjd`

Why does this happen when it should match < > equally in the lookahead?

Comment: I somehow even broke the markup parser on stackoverflow, as it doesn't seem to have bolded 90% of the text I bolded.  This is the kind of day I'm having!

Comment: Might I add that the very similar regex test(?=(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$) works perfectly for finding the terms not inside of quotations. (If the test case were changed of course)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to match pairs of `<>` in the lookahead; you probably just want to make that no `>` follows `test` unless a `<` appears first.  (You can't do the same in the reverse direction; the JavaScript regular expression engine doesn't support variable-length lookbehind.)

```
test(?=[^>]*(?:<|$))
```

Comment: Thanks, this works! But can you explain why matching pairs failed??

Comment: Matching pairs isn't the right approach; you need to make sure that `test` isn't _inside_ a pair.  So, you need make sure `test` isn't followed by the wrong "half-pair".

Comment: Out of curiosity, is this same thing possible if the markers are a sequence?  Like the words "start" and "end" for instance, or something like that?

Comment: Yes: `test(?=(?:(?!end).)*start|(?:(?!start|end).)*$)`

Comment: I had just written that same thing right as I checked the comment; it works though. Thanks!

Comment: Actually it works but not with newlines for some reason, is there a way to fix that also?  Your answer DOES work with newlines, but your comment for start and end does not.

Comment: Nevermind I figured it out, using [\s\S] in the place of the . actually matches \n since javascript has no dotall flag

Comment: After an "aha" moment on the way to work this morning, simplified the regexp in my answer.  So my start/end example above would simplify to: `test(?=(?:(?!end).)*(?:start|$))`

Answer (score 1):

your lookahead zero-width assertion expression uses

```
[^<]*
```

and this means "any char except `<`", but that includes `>`. So for example

```
<test>
```

will match `test` because `test` is followed by `>` (that matches "anything but `<`") and then the string ends.

Comment: You are referring to the last occurrence of this right?  I thought (?:[^<]*<[^>]*>)* would match as far as it could.

Comment: @Nowayz: for the example yes, but the same problem would be present for `<test><>`: it would still match `test` because the first `[^<]` in this case would get past the `>`. Note that a regexp quantifier by default matches as much as possible that still allows the rest to match (i.e. can also match less than the maximum for that quantifier). Greedy/non-greedy never influences if a regexp matches or not, but only what ends up in specific groups.